Unreasonably High CPU Usage While Doing Simple Tasks
I am currently migrating a robot control software to ROS2 (from vanilla C++).
While doing so, i came across a number of issues related to the performance of the ros2 project. The specifics of the project are:

The hardware is a Raspberry Pi 5
It is connected to four CAN busses (each with a maximum throughput of 1Mbit/s)
The workspace contains eight nodes, one is a compile-time composed node consisting of 14 smaller nodes
All CAN messages get published onto individual topics, each with automatically generated custom message definitions
In total there are 314 publishers and 179 subscriptions (of the publishers, the majority isnt used, they are just automatically created for each CAN message definition)
When the robot is idle, ~2500 CAN messages are incoming per second, which translates to the same amount of messages on topics.

When the robot is idle, basically no computation is done. Still, with this exact setup, all four cores of the Pi are used up and message processing gets a serious latency (double-digit seconds).
I have verified that the publisher node which translates CAN messages to ROS topics is relatively efficient (~12 us per CAN message) and is not causing this problem.
When looking at which processes take up the CPU, its mostly the composed node (althoug when starting the nodes individually, without composition, each one takes up roughly the same amount of cpu usage) and the process started by ros2 launch.
While i recognize that the compute power of an RPi4 is limited, the total amount of data that needs to be processed does not seem that high to me (e.g. 4K live streaming and encoding is handled by the Pi completely fine and the bandwidth required by that is lot more).
This is why i feel like i am missing something. I am relatively new to ROS and have mostly just tinkered around with different things to see if it makes a difference. Previously, i mostly used services instead of topics, but i thought that that probably generates too much overhead (which it did, but it also didnt fix the performance problems). All of the topic subscription callbacks basically just set a variable in the nodes and dont do any computation.
I have used the tracing tools to see if anything takes a lot of time, but all callbacks are in the sub-millisecond range, which seems okay to me.
Any help would be appreciated! I see that it may be difficult to identify performance bottlenecks without any code, but i am not even sure which parts of the project could be interesting, so i am asking this question without any snippets.
Edit: Another thing i tried was to use the Eclipse Cyclone DDS implementation, which reduced CPU usage by about 25%.

Are you building your C++ nodes with compiler optimizations? Release mode is a non-default option in Colcon builds, see e.g. https://github.com/colcon/colcon-cmake/issues/96

I was surprised to notice that in a plain colcon build ... the compiler invocation has no optimization flags

You can pass CMake arguments to Colcon using the --cmake-args flag, see https://colcon.readthedocs.io/en/released/reference/verb/build.html#cmake-specific-arguments
I usually add --cmake-args -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo

Thank you so much! This actually decreased the cpu usage considerably. It is still way higher than i would expect, but unfourtunately it seems like i just have to deal with the current amount.
